# How to update the page for the next search from an API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

In this app, when I submit a word (for example "help") for the first time then it will return the search results and renders it on the page, but if I searched for another word then the results wont be displayed until and unless I refresh the page. How can I render next search results on the page? The codepen link is here: https://codepen.io/nelsonuprety1/pen/KKWreRQ . To search for new results the page should be refreshed.

```js
'use strict';


const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

const meaningContainer = document.querySelector('.meanings');

const renderSynonym = function (data) {
  const html = `
    <ul class="mean">
         <li>${data.meanings[0].definitions[0].synonyms}</li>
     </ul>
    `;
  meaningContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  meaningContainer.style.opacity = 1;
};

function getSynonym() {
  const searches = document.querySelector('#search');
  const search = searches.value.trim();
  // searches.value = '';

  if (search === '') return;
  fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/${search}`)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function ([data]) {
      renderSynonym(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  // searches.value = '';
}

submit.addEventListener('click', getSynonym);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend:wght@100;300;400;500&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* css variables */
:root {
  --text-color: #001858;
}

body {
  background: #659999;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #f4791f, #659999);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f4791f, #659999);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

header {
  color: var(--text-color);
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2em;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.searchBox {
  /* display: flex;
    justify-content: center; */
  background-color: #ced8c5;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  /* center a div horizontally if we use margin:0 auto */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.find {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 1000;
  line-height: 2.15;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#search {
  /* width: 100%; */
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline-color: #659999;
}

#submit {
  height: 40px;
  width: 20%;
}

#submit:hover {
  background-color: #8fd9a8;
}

/* 
.mean.hidden {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    gap: 9px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 40px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
   
} */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.meanings {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #ced8c5;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  min-width: 30rem;
  min-height: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  font-family: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mean {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  min-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="Find synonyms, near synonyms." />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Synonymous : Find Similar Words</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Synonymous : Find Synonyms</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="searchBox">
      <label for="synonymFind" class="find">Find the Synonym</label>
      <input
        type="search"
        id="search"
        placeholder="Search Synonymous"
        autocapitalize="off"
        autocomplete="off"
        autofocus
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit" />
    </div>

    <main class="container">
      <div class="meanings">
        <h1>Synonyms</h1>
        <!-- <ul class="mean">
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
     </ul> -->
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your code works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/mhnLa5y3/ The question is unclear. I've tried multiple searches without page reload.

Comment: @jabaa can you please check the html and css code here and try https://codepen.io/nelsonuprety1/pen/KKWreRQ   . I cannot get new results without refreshing the page the dom wont update . I want the page to display new results without refreshing the page

Comment: Please add all necessary resources to your question.

Comment: @jabaa Here is the link: https://codepen.io/nelsonuprety1/pen/KKWreRQ thank you.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are self-contained. Stack Overflow is Q&A platform with the goal to help future users to find answers to their problems (read the [tour]). Your link can change or become invalid. Therefore it's required to add all necessary resources directly to your question.

Comment: @jabaa i have made the necessary edits thank you

Comment: New results are added to the right of the old result and leave the view port. The code works. Each search adds a new result but after the third search you can't see them.

Comment: @jabaa how can i fix this problem

Comment: Remove `display: flex;` from `.meanings`.

Comment: @jabaa thank you for the help. But how do i remove previous data and display only the search results that i queried for? Remove old data from the page after searching for new data

Comment: Why do you add new results with `meaningContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);`? You can overwrite the old result with `meaningContainer.innerHTML = html;`

Comment: @jabaa thank you so much for the help the issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are adding new results to the right. After some searches the new results leave the view port and you can't see them. You can remove `display: flex;` in `.meanings` to change this behavior:

```js
'use strict';


const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

const meaningContainer = document.querySelector('.meanings');

const renderSynonym = function (data) {
  const html = `
    <ul class="mean">
         <li>${data.meanings[0].definitions[0].synonyms}</li>
     </ul>
    `;
  meaningContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  meaningContainer.style.opacity = 1;
};

function getSynonym() {
  const searches = document.querySelector('#search');
  const search = searches.value.trim();
  // searches.value = '';

  if (search === '') return;
  fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/${search}`)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function ([data]) {
      renderSynonym(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  // searches.value = '';
}

submit.addEventListener('click', getSynonym);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend:wght@100;300;400;500&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* css variables */
:root {
  --text-color: #001858;
}

body {
  background: #659999;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #f4791f, #659999);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f4791f, #659999);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

header {
  color: var(--text-color);
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2em;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.searchBox {
  /* display: flex;
    justify-content: center; */
  background-color: #ced8c5;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  /* center a div horizontally if we use margin:0 auto */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.find {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 1000;
  line-height: 2.15;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#search {
  /* width: 100%; */
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline-color: #659999;
}

#submit {
  height: 40px;
  width: 20%;
}

#submit:hover {
  background-color: #8fd9a8;
}

/* 
.mean.hidden {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    gap: 9px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 40px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
   
} */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.meanings {
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #ced8c5;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  min-width: 30rem;
  min-height: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  font-family: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mean {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  min-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="Find synonyms, near synonyms." />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Synonymous : Find Similar Words</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Synonymous : Find Synonyms</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="searchBox">
      <label for="synonymFind" class="find">Find the Synonym</label>
      <input
        type="search"
        id="search"
        placeholder="Search Synonymous"
        autocapitalize="off"
        autocomplete="off"
        autofocus
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit" />
    </div>

    <main class="container">
      <div class="meanings">
        <h1>Synonyms</h1>
        <!-- <ul class="mean">
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
     </ul> -->
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

or overwrite the previous result with

```js
'use strict';


const submit = document.querySelector('#submit');

const meaningContainer = document.querySelector('.meanings');

const renderSynonym = function (data) {
  const html = `
    <ul class="mean">
         <li>${data.meanings[0].definitions[0].synonyms}</li>
     </ul>
    `;
  meaningContainer.innerHTML = html;
  meaningContainer.style.opacity = 1;
};

function getSynonym() {
  const searches = document.querySelector('#search');
  const search = searches.value.trim();
  // searches.value = '';

  if (search === '') return;
  fetch(`https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/${search}`)
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function ([data]) {
      renderSynonym(data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  // searches.value = '';
}

submit.addEventListener('click', getSynonym);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lexend:wght@100;300;400;500&display=swap');

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* css variables */
:root {
  --text-color: #001858;
}

body {
  background: #659999;
  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #f4791f, #659999);
  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f4791f, #659999);
  /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

header {
  color: var(--text-color);
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2em;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.searchBox {
  /* display: flex;
    justify-content: center; */
  background-color: #ced8c5;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 50%;
  /* center a div horizontally if we use margin:0 auto */
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.find {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 1000;
  line-height: 2.15;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#search {
  /* width: 100%; */
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline-color: #659999;
}

#submit {
  height: 40px;
  width: 20%;
}

#submit:hover {
  background-color: #8fd9a8;
}

/* 
.mean.hidden {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    gap: 9px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 40px;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
   
} */

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.meanings {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #ced8c5;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  min-width: 30rem;
  min-height: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 2rem;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  font-family: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mean {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  min-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  margin: 0 3rem;
  padding: 2rem;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="Find synonyms, near synonyms." />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Synonymous : Find Similar Words</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Synonymous : Find Synonyms</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="searchBox">
      <label for="synonymFind" class="find">Find the Synonym</label>
      <input
        type="search"
        id="search"
        placeholder="Search Synonymous"
        autocapitalize="off"
        autocomplete="off"
        autofocus
      />
      <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit" />
    </div>

    <main class="container">
      <div class="meanings">
        <h1>Synonyms</h1>
        <!-- <ul class="mean">
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
         <li>...</li>
     </ul> -->
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```